# Importing string from HTML into markdown parser

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a markdown parser that works great if I pass it a string like this:

```
el.innerHTML = marked('#Introduction:\nHere you can write some text.');
```

But if I have that string inside HTML and send it to parser like

```
el.innerHTML = marked(otherEl.innerHTML);
```

it does not get parsed. Why is this? Does the *string* format of `.innerHTML` do something I am missing?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5p8be1b4/

My HTML:

```
<div id="editor">
    <div class="contentTarget"></div>
    <div class="contentSource">#Introduction:\nHere you can write some text.</div>
</div>
```

`div.contentTarget` should receive HTML, parsed markdown. But it receives a un-parsed string only.

In the image bellow is the jsFiddle output. A unformated `div.contentTarget`, the original `div.contentSource` where I get the innerHTML to use in `div.contentTarget` and in the bottom, a working parsed `div#tester` which received a string directly into the parser.

[image]

Comment: The function `marked` doesn't exist.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel it comes in the dependencies of jsFiddle, and you can see it working in the example there also.

Comment: Sorry. But I don't see any mistake. And I didn't noticed the dependency. It is working as expected.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the output in `div.contentTarget` is wrong, its not parsed HTML, its still markdown. That is the problem.

Comment: It renders an `<h1>`, which is fine. Or you expect it to also render `\n` as a `<br>`?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel if you look at the jsFiddle, the `div#tester` receives both parsed headers and normal text. That is what I expect in the other one using `innerHTML`.

Comment: Can you show it in a stacksnippet? Because I don't see anything wrong with your jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with you. Better debug the marked.js

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel added a image and description.

Comment: it's got something to do with \n. closing in on it

Comment: ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912535/importing-string-from-html-into-markdown-parser#comment49863479_30912535 ... So, you expect it to render as a `<br>`...

Comment: @EmreTürkiş if I do `markdown.innerHTML` I get exactly the same `"#Introduction:\nHere you can write some text."` in the console. So seems good so far...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes, I want it to read markdown, ie I want the parser to read the string passed properly so he can do his jobb.

Comment: so how are we doing on this?

Comment: dude, could you please close the issue? god...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is around your newlines.  When you put `\n` inside a string in javascript, you're putting an actual newline character in it.

The same `\n` inside your HTML content is just that, `\n`.  It is *not* a newline.  If you change your HTML to this (with an *actual* newline), it works as expected:

```
<div class="contentSource">#Introduction:
Here you can write some text.</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j0pg2st/1/)

Alternatively, if you change your javascript string to:

```
test.innerHTML = marked('#Introduction:\\nHere you can write some text.');
```

So that the string actually contains `\n` rather than a newline, you see the same erroneous behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is rendering differently because Javascript automatically interprets `\n` as a newline.

Consider the following:

```
alert('a\ntest');
```

Which will have an alert with 2 lines.

And now, consider the following:

```
<span>a\ntest</span>

<script>
    alert(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML);
</script>
```

This will show `a\ntest`.

To fix it, use this:

```
el.innerHTML = marked(otherEl.innerHTML.replace(/\\n/g,'\n'));
```

Or, a more general and secure way:

```
el.innerHTML = marked(
    otherEl
        .innerHTML
        .replace(
            /\\([btnvfr"'\\])/g,
            function(_,c){
                return {
                        b:'\b',
                        t:'\t',
                        v:'\v',
                        n:'\n',
                        r:'\r',
                        '"':'"',
                        "'":"'",
                        '\\':'\\'
                    }[c];
            }
        )
    );
```

Or, if you like it minimal and you are ready to have cthulhu knocking on your front door, use this:

```
el.innerHTML = marked(otherEl.innerHTML.replace(/\\([btnvfr])/g,function(_,c){return eval('return "\\'+c+'"');}));
```

Comment: @JamesThorpe It would evaluate the escape sequence. But it isn't a secure way.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

In your html, you have \n, but it's supposed to be a line-break, and you should use br becasue this is supposed to be html.

```
<div class="contentSource">#Introduction:<br/>Here you can write some text.</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div class="contentSource">#Introduction:\nHere you can write some text.</div>
```

When you debug the code, if you send the innerHTML to marked, it shows this as a function parameter:

```
#Introduction:\nHere you can write some text.
```

But when you send the string in the js, it shows the parameter like this:

```
#Introduction:
Here you can write some text.
```

Hope this helps.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gbrkj901/11/

Comment: to further the issue: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1291-ask-ben-rendering-javascript-line-breaks.htm